# Is there any way to log Excel Add-In Exception (no code change)?

Tags: .net, excel, logging, add-in

We have an old Excel COM AddIn written in C# which has no log built-in. 
Now one client has an issue, when he clicks one ribbon button,  a windows form shows up for half a second and then disappears. but it should stay. 
In initialization of the window form, it makes two web service calls to get data to populate controls on the form.
I guess something wrong in initialization. but can't tell without log. 
So I wonder if there is any tool/way to log exceptions/errors occurred in Excel?

Thanks a lot!

Edit 
I am thinking VBA now since I did not find a tool to accomplish this

```
        On Error GoTo ERR_      
        Dim cmd As CommandBarButton
        Set cmd = Application.CommandBars("MyTab").Controls("MyRibbonButton")
        cmd.Execute       
        Exit 
ERR_:
    MsgBox ("Error " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description & " LastDllError:" & Err.LastDllError & Err.Source)
```

Hopefully that will give me some clue. not sure how much info I can get until run this on client's side.  thanks

Comment: Good plan. Also I suggest you read thoroughly [Chip Pearson's page on error handling](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm). Take note of the section on "Error Handling With Multiple Procedures".